Cannot resolve symbol 'widget' for import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;
I'm currently migrating my project to Androidx, after using the refactor option in android studio I still have few support lib imports in classes.
When I tried changing 'import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;' to 'import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;', I got below compile error
Cannot resolve symbol 'widget'
I'm currently using 'Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 (Jan 2023)' and all the support dependencies are replaced with androidx.

update your android sdk tools

It sounds like the appcompat library didn't get added to your Gradle dependencies properly.
As described on the appcompat page on the Android Developers site, add the following to the dependencies { block of your app-level build.gradle:

def appcompat_version = "1.6.1" // or whatever the latest version is on the above-linked page

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
// For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"


